# XMLRPC invalid protocol version exception

Tags: java, apache

Please i have an issue with my xmlrpc client. I get an
"org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransportException: HTTP server
returned unexpected status: Invalid protocol version Not defined" exception
when i run the client.

Exception trace:

org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransportException: HTTP server returned
unexpected status: Invalid protocol version Not defined
        at
org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcCommonsTransport.checkStatus(XmlRpcCommonsTransport.java:261)
        at
org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcCommonsTransport.getInputStream(XmlRpcCommonsTransport.java:119)
        at
org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:152)
        at
org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:143)
        at
org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:56)
        at
org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:167)
        at
org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:158)
        at
org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:147)

Please any help will be highly appreciated as i have been battling with
this issue for a while now.

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: That could be either the HTTP specification or the XMLRPC spec you are using - can you get any wire level trace out of this?